# Twilio MMS: GIFs sent via Twilio do not play inline

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using the Twilio PHP SDK within a Laravel app to send MMS messages.

When I send JPG or PNG files, the images display inline. When I send GIF files, the GIFs are sent as objects that the user must click on to view. They behave more like an attachment than an inline image.

[The gif displays as a clickable object rather than as an inline gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gonf3.jpg)

The code for constructing the object to be sent is dead simple with the helper SDK, perhaps overly so.

```
$response = new MessagingResponse();
$answer = $response->message("");
$answer->body("Foo");
$answer->media("/bar.gif");
print $response;
```

This sends the file.  It is captured by Twilio and turned into a Twilio Media Resource before being sent to the user.  My understanding is that GIFs are a fully supported content type in Twilio so my expectation is that they would be displayed the same way that a JPG is.

Is there some other factor I'm missing here? Or am I missing an element in the construction of the object?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're using the [Media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types#supported-mime-types) resource to send a media file. When you do this, the content will be [formatted for delivery on the destination device](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types#supported-mime-types).

Instead of Media, try `mediaURL` and pass in a URL to the gif. You can use [Twilio Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/assets#get-started-with-assets) to upload a media file yourself and make it accessible via URL.

Hope that helps!